# highlight text with surrounding words

Tags: php, regex

i want to highlight text in a given string with given keywords and add a random number of surrounding words.

**Example sentence:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed.

**Example keyword:**

> dolore magna

**Desired result:**
*(mark 0-4 words before and after the keyword*

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor `invidunt ut labore et **dolore magna** aliquyam erat, sed`.

**What did i try?**

`( [\w,\.-\?]+){0,5} ".$myKeyword." (.+ ){2,5}`
and
`([a-zA-Z,. ]+){1,3} ".$n." ([a-zA-Z,. ]+){1,3}`

Any ideas how to improve this and make it more robust?

Comment: What qualifies the amount of words before/after the keyword?

Comment: i want to pass rand(min,max) as qualifier for the amount before / after

Comment: i will review your answer now and make some tests

Comment: What happened with this question? Either answer worked?

Answer (score 5):

For highlighting use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function. Here's an idea:   `$s = "dolore magna";`

```
$str = preg_replace(
       '/\b(?>[\'\w-]+\W+){0,4}'.preg_quote($s, "/").'(?:\W+[\'\w-]+){0,4}/i',
       '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

Test the [pattern at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rK9fS2/2) or [php test at eval.in](https://eval.in/410396).   `echo $str;`

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor **invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed**.

Using `i` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for caseless matching - drop if not wanted. First group `?>` [atomic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) for performance.

- As word character I used `['\w-]` (`\w` [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for word character, `'` and `-`)
- `\W` matches a character, that is not a word character (negated `\w`)
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Used it for better performance.

Comment: this works great, but somehow the highlight starts or ends within the middle of a word on some sentences.

Comment: @unr3al011 Can you give a sample?

Comment: i discovered something: the partial highlight only applies when a word contains umlauts (öäüÖÄÜß)

Comment: @unr3al011 If the input is utf-8 use the `u (PCRE_UTF8)` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) ...`{0,4}/iu`. This would extend `\w`

Comment: ok works great, only one last problem i encounter: when matching multiple highlighting keywords, it destroys some html tags. see: https://eval.in/410464

Comment: @unr3al011 Use `[^\w><]` instead of the upper `\W` (didn't know, you want to use that on html) so pattern becomes [like this](https://regex101.com/r/tL5xS2/1): `/\b(?>['\w-]+[^\w><]+){0,4}dolore magna(?:[^\w><]+['\w-]+){0,4}/iu`

Comment: great man! you're a true regex master! will do some more test cases and later today or tomorrow check your answer correct :) helped me alot, thx

Comment: @unr3al011 thanks, no problem! glad it works for now :]

Comment: @unr3al011 If you really want to use this on html, at least additionally try to skip the tags by using something like `<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)` see [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tL5xS2/3). So the final pattern becomes like that: `/<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(?>['\w-]+[^\w><]+){0,4}dolore magna(?:[^\w><]+['\w-]+){0,4}/ius` Highly recommended to not parse html with regex. Different problems could arise.

Comment: i am not parsing html, but when i want to highlight multiple keywords, i have to iterate over an array of keywords and from these comes the only html. i am applying this regex to plaintext only

Comment: @unr3al011 I see - pattern can also be an array as input for preg_replace - if that helps. If there's html already in the string, the last pattern with `(*SKIP)(*F)` is the most safe.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would accomplish what you are after. Please see the demo for an explanation of everything the regex is doing, or post a comment if you have a question.

Regex:

```
((?:[\w,.\-?]+\h){0,5})\b' . . '\b((?:.+\h){2,5})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vG8qT2/1

PHP:

```
<?php
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed.';
$term = 'dolore magna';
$min = 0;
$max = 5;
preg_match('~((?:[\w,.\-?]+\h){'.$min.','.$max. '})\b' . preg_quote($term) . '\b((?:.+\h){'.$min.','.$max.'})~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/410063

Note the captured values will be in `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`.